# How to deal with attrition problem in panel data

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data

I'm trying to test a certain "treatment effect" with panel survey data, and facing a problem with potential attrition bias. There are some observations from the baseline years missing in the follow-up years. I ran a regression of the probability of missing in the follow-up years on the treatment status, and the results showed that the probability of attrition is significantly correlated with the treatment status. Based on that, I guess I cannot say that the panel attrition is random. I am wondering if there are methods to deal with panel data attrition bias, or other robustness checks that I could rely on. Many thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to say methods to deal with panel data **attrition** bias?

Comment: Yes, I meant "attrition bias", so sorry about that, and thanks for pointing out. Now I'm trying to use inverse probability weighted (IPW) estimators to deal with the attrition bias.